# List properties with empty (undefined) values in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

If I have a JavaScript object:

```
var object = {
  propertyOne: undefined,
  propertyTwo: 'defined',
  propertyThree: 'defined',
  propertyFour: undefined
}
```

How can I create a method that will list the properties with undefined values (in the example's case, propertyOne and propertyFour).

I'm quite new to JavaScript, and this is what I had so far:

```
function getEmptyProperties(object) {
  var emptyProps = [];
  for (var property in object) {
    if (object.property === undefined) {
      emptyProps += property
    }
  }
  return emptyProps
}
```

But this returns ALL of the properties, regardless if they are undefined or not.

I know I'm missing some things that are principal in JS, but can't figure it out. Kindly help please?

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the object with:

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(function(val, i){
  if (object[val] === undefined){
  //do things to save the properties you want to save or delete
  }
})
```

For fundamentals I might suggest [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/). It's free.
You have a number of syntax errors in your code that could be fixed if you read the first 6ish chapters.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getEmptyProperties = function(object) {
  var emptyProps = [];
  for (var property in object) {
    if (object[property] === undefined) {
      emptyProps.push(property);
    }
  }
  return emptyProps
}
```

Comment: You should explain what this code does and how, so it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), to get an array of only the properties that are `undefined`:

```
var obj = {
    propertyOne: undefined,
    propertyTwo: 'defined',
    propertyThree: 'defined',
    propertyFour: undefined
};

var undefProps = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (key) {
    return obj[key] === undefined;
});

// undefProps: ["propertyOne", "propertyFour"]
```

And with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)!:

```
var undefProps = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k] === undefined);
```